# Drop down bug says +30 but I only got +10

Tags: bug, reputation, activity-dropdown

See screen shot below... I got +10, but the drop down shows +30.

[image]

oh, I see I cut off the rest of the day -- here is the top of the Reputation audit:

[image]

nb - this problem has persisted since yesterday including two different machines and and at least one reboot.  I'm using chrome.

**UPDATE** -- new feature verified, not a bug on mouse hover details shown:

[image]

Comment: You're +30 on that post for the month, if you hover over the number it should tell you the timeframe it's using.

Comment: @TimStone - exactly correct, see new screen shot.  Maybe I should delete this question?  Or leave it if someone else has the problem?